# I am working on a project and I am creating a file called geolocation_client.py. I keep receiving errors and pycharm keeps telling me to install stash

Tags: python, pycharm, geocoding

I am working on a project and I am creating a file called geolocation_client.py. I keep receiving errors and pycharm keeps telling me to install stash, but I am unable to.
Below is an example of an error I received.

```
   print("the stash is at ", stash.__str__())
NameError: name 'stash' is not defined
```

```
from geolocation import GeoLocation

def main():
    stash = GeoLocation(34.988889, -106.614444)
    ABQstudio = GeoLocation(34.989978, -106.614357)
    FBIbuilding = GeoLocation(35.131281, -106.61263)

print("the stash is at ", stash.__str__())
print("ABQ stuido is at ", ABQstudio.__str__())
print("FBI building is at ", FBIbuilding.__str__())

print("distance in miles between:")
stash_studio = stash.distance_from(ABQstudio)
stash_fbi = stash.distance_from(FBIbuilding)

print(" stash/studio = ", stash_studio)
print(" stash/fbi = ", stash_fbi)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: (1) "stash" in "main()" is only a local variable (doesn't exist outside "main"). You can declare it "global" instead. (2) "main" must be called first to define "stash" before it can be used outside of the function.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help and explaining why my program was not compiling properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing a variable that does not exist outside of the function

try:

```
from geolocation import GeoLocation

def main():
    stash = GeoLocation(34.988889, -106.614444)
    ABQstudio = GeoLocation(34.989978, -106.614357)
    FBIbuilding = GeoLocation(35.131281, -106.61263)

    print("the stash is at ", stash.__str__())
    print("ABQ stuido is at ", ABQstudio.__str__())
    print("FBI building is at ", FBIbuilding.__str__())

    print("distance in miles between:")
    stash_studio = stash.distance_from(ABQstudio)
    stash_fbi = stash.distance_from(FBIbuilding)

    print(" stash/studio = ", stash_studio)
    print(" stash/fbi = ", stash_fbi)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I now see where I went wrong on my code.